# May Jews have non-Jews/minors make dough with their ingredients to be Petur from challah (if they own the dough)

Tags: halacha, challah-shabbat-bread, yoreh-deah, separating-challah, petur-exemption

According to Halacha, is it permissible for a Jew to give their eggs/flour to a gentile or a minor Jew to knead so they are exempt from Terumat Challah (when the jew still owns the dough)?  So if a Jew gives their ingredients to either of those groups and instructs them to make dough  without instructing them to remove Terumat challah, is that permissible or not?

Is this question discussed in the Poskim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obligation to separate Challah is based on the owner of the ingredients at the time of kneading, not the person who actually did the kneading (YD 330:1).

Comment: I see that the edit to the question, makes its way around this answer.